# Find the possible values of the natural number $N$ if $N^{5}+7N$ has exactly four natural factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is what I got so far.

$N^{5}+7N=N(N^{4}+7)$

For exactly four natural factors, we have two cases:

1. $N(N^{4}+7)=s^3$, where $s$ is a prime number.
2. $N(N^{4}+7)=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

For case 1, it is possible in two different cases:

- $N=1$ and $N^4+7$ is a cube of a prime number. We can see that $N^4+7=8$ when $N=1$, which is $2^3$. So, $N=1$ is a possible value for N.
- $N^4+7$ is a square of a prime number, and $N^2=N^4+7$. There are no such $N$ for this, so this case is impossible.

For case 2, it is possible in two different cases:

- $N=2$ and $N^4+7$ is a prime number. We can see that $N^4+7=23$ when $N=2$, which is prime. So, $N=2$ is a possible value of $N$.
- $N>2$, and $N$ and $N^4+7$ are prime numbers.

<s>I'm stuck in this part. How do you prove or disprove "$N>2$, and $N$ and $N^4+7$ are prime numbers"? Or is my approach to this question needlessly complicated?</s> Thanks @lulu for this.

- $N>2$, and $N$ and $N^4+7$ are prime numbers. $N$ must be odd, so $N^4$ is odd, and thus $N^4+7$ is even and cannot be prime. So there is no such $N$.

So the possible $N$ is only $1$ and $2$.

Now that I have found the answer, I feel that my method is quite tedious to do. Is there any other method that is more compact?

Comment: The [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) would tell us that there are infinitely many $n$ for which $n^4+7$ is prime, though of course $n>2$ can't then also be prime (if $n$ is prime, other  than $n=2$, then $n^4+7$ is even).

Comment: Note that for prime numbers other than $2,3$, $N^4+7 \not \equiv \pm 1 \bmod 6$ and hence cannot be prime. This means $N^4+7$ is composite. Knowing this should afford the answer you seek.

Comment: @KeithBackman I'm still quite unfamiliar with modular arithmetics. Can you explain why you used mod 6 and why being not equivalent to $\pm1\mod 6$ proves that $N^4+7$ is composite?

Comment: 6n+k, where k=0,2,3,4 is always divisible by 2 or 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following way may be simpler.

$N=1$ is a possible value.

For $N>1$, $N(N^4+7)$ has at least four factors $1,N,N^4+7$ and $N(N^4+7)$.

So, $N$ has to be a prime number.

$N=2$ is a possible value.

If $N$ is an odd prime, then $N^4+7$ is even, so $N(N^4+7)$ has another factor $2$.

Comment: Ah, so my second case for case 1 is a given?

Comment: @Zero : Sorry, but I don't get your comment. The key point of this answer is that we don't have to separate it into two cases. For $N>1$, $N(N^4+7)$ has at least four factors, which implies that $N$ has to be a prime number.

Comment: Ah, okay. So the point is we need to know first that $N=1$ is a possible value before finding other values among $N>1$? Thanks.

Comment: @Zero : Let me explain my thought. First, looking at $N(N^4+7)$, I thought that this has at least four factors $1,N,N^4+7$ and $N(N^4+7)$. But then I realized that $N$ has to be larger than $1$ in order to have four *distinct* factors. So, I knew that I have to deal with the case $N=1$ separately. This is how I thought.

Comment: Ah, okay! Makes sense now. Many thanks.